# Visual C++ nuget: boost include files not found

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, nuget

I'm pretty new to visual studio as I usually work in linux.

I installed boost package via nuget and I can see all the headers files installed correctly into my solution's 'packages' folder.

However whenever I try to include a boost header I get an error, e.g:

`Cannot open include file: 'boost/type_traits/has_equal_to.hpp': No such file or directory`

At the same time I installed SFML libraries and those work perfectly.

Also I noticed, that in my project properties, 'Referenced Packages' section SFML libraries are listed, but boost ones are not. This is strange, because when I installed the packages I did click the checkboxes for the projects I installed the packages for.

I tried hard to find how to add package references but miserably failed. I'm probably just being thin here...

I'm using Visual Sudio 14 (2015) Update 3 Community Edition.

Comment: 1. Which version of Boost are you using?
2. Which Boost NuGet packages are installed to your project?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the following path:

```
$(SolutionDir)\packages\boost.w.x.y.z\lib\native\include\boost
```

in Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories

Comment: Why do you need to add this? Shouldn't this be automatically added by the nuget target?

Comment: Not an ideal solution; this will have to be revisited every time a dependency version changes.